# elasticsearch connection refused error

Tags: elasticsearch, debian

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04) article to install and configure elasticsearch on my system, both the installation and configuration worked fine but when i try to run elasticsearch:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

i get this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

**EDIT: 1**

after @val suggestion:

```
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
```

it returned as:

```
    elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendo
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-05-24 09:11:16 IST; 2h 17mi
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 5043 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DI
  Process: 5039 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-
 Main PID: 5043 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 24 09:11:16 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
May 24 09:11:16 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
May 24 09:11:16 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited,
May 24 09:11:16 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed 
May 24 09:11:16 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result '
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

**Edit 2:**

*journalctrl -f results*

```
May 25 08:35:31 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
May 25 08:35:31 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
May 25 08:35:31 ahmed-pc sudo[6256]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 25 08:35:42 ahmed-pc dhclient[3644]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.43.121 on wlp3s0 to 192.168.43.1 port 67 (xid=0x4be71b5a)
May 25 08:35:42 ahmed-pc dhclient[3644]: DHCPACK of 192.168.43.121 from 192.168.43.1
May 25 08:35:42 ahmed-pc dhclient[3644]: bound to 192.168.43.121 -- renewal in 1339 seconds.
May 25 08:35:43 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 25 08:35:43 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 25 08:35:43 ahmed-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Have you started elasticsearch with `sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch`? What does `sudo systemctl status elasticsearch` say?

Comment: Hi, please try checking your journal for more detailed messages. 
In one console tail to your journal: `journalctl -f`  then in another terminal window try to start elastic `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch` . Do you see any error messages? it could be helpful.

Comment: @MarcosMaia thanks for your suggestion i did checked the logs but since am new it doesn't made sense to me, i have updated the questions with results see if you can help.

Comment: Hum.. it looks like something with permissions? Can you give permission to elastic user and group recursively where elasticsearch is installed and also to data and logs folders, I believe it will fix it.